# Finding a C struct or header in man pages?

Tags: command-line, c, manpage

When programming in C, I like to use man sections 2 and 3 to look up the form of system and library calls.

But I also often need to look up the form of a struct that is defined in a standard library. For example, sockaddr/sockaddr_un in 'sys/socket.h'. Is there any way I can look up structs or header files through man pages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find these, it's helpful to use, for example, `apropos socket` to see which man pages may correspond to the information you desire. In this case, it's `man 7 unix`:

```
#define UNIX_PATH_MAX    108
struct sockaddr_un {
    sa_family_t sun_family;               /* AF_UNIX */
    char        sun_path[UNIX_PATH_MAX];  /* pathname */
};
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Helpful, I did not know about apropos. But this still leaves something to be desired. For example, I would not be able to find the man page for socketaddr_in by `apropos socket`. (It's under `man 7 ip`) But there may not be a better solution?

Comment: No, not unless you want to let your IDE pick those things up for you.

Comment: What kind of an IDE will pick up those things for me, for free on Linux?