# no manual entry for string.h

Tags: 16.04, c, documentation, manpage

I am trying to find a manual entry for "string.h", I have GNU gcc installed. But when I input `man string.h`, it shows me `no manual entry for string.h`, I am not sure what went wrong? Can anyone help me please? Thank you!

Comment: Manuals have subscripts. If i recall correctly , strings.h is subscript 2, so try `man -e 2 string`. I am on mobile, so unfortunately can't post a more detailed answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding a C struct or header in man pages?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/93953/finding-a-c-struct-or-header-in-man-pages)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `man man`, we can see that manual pages fall into the following sections:

```
   1   Executable programs or shell commands
   2   System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
   3   Library calls (functions within program libraries)
   4   Special files (usually found in /dev)
   5   File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
   6   Games
   7   Miscellaneous  (including  macro  packages  and  conventions), e.g.
       man(7), groff(7)
   8   System administration commands (usually only for root)
   9   Kernel routines [Non standard]
```

Note that Section 3 is for `functions within program libraries` i.e. it is generally individual functions that are documented, rather than specific header files. So for example `man strncpy`:

```
STRCPY(3)                  Linux Programmer's Manual                 STRCPY(3)

NAME
       strcpy, strncpy - copy a string

SYNOPSIS
       #include <string.h>

       char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);

       char *strncpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n);

DESCRIPTION
       The  strcpy()  function  copies the string pointed to by src, including
       the terminating null byte ('\0'), to the buffer  pointed  to  by  dest.
       The  strings  may  not overlap, and the destination string dest must be
       large enough to receive the copy.  Beware  of  buffer  overruns!   (See
       BUGS.)
etc.
```

---

In this case there is an overview in `man string` (as there is for `stdio` - but not, apparently, for `stdlib`)

```
STRING(3)                  Linux Programmer's Manual                 STRING(3)

NAME
       stpcpy,  strcasecmp,  strcat, strchr, strcmp, strcoll, strcpy, strcspn,
       strdup, strfry, strlen, strncat, strncmp, strncpy,  strncasecmp,  strp‐
       brk,  strrchr, strsep, strspn, strstr, strtok, strxfrm, index, rindex -
       string operations

SYNOPSIS
       #include <strings.h>
etc.
```

**NB not to be confused with** `man strings` which documents the `strings` command line utility from section (1) of the catalog.

Comment: Also, these are in `manpages-dev` - not sure if that's installed by default